# Does Google detect keywords put in grammatically correct forms?

Tags: seo, keywords

I'm writing blog posts for clients and I wrote an article entitled: "4 ways to finance your TPE or PME" (TPE = very small company, PME = small or middle-sized company). The keywords that seemed the most natural were therefore: Finance tpe pme.

I use the WordPress Yoast plugin in order to check my SEO and although the three words appear in the title and several time in the article, because they are put in grammatically correct forms ("finance your TPE or PME, financing of your TPE or PME), Yoast considers that they simply do not appear anywhere.

I am wondering if google is just as stupid or if what I did worked for good SEO.

Comment: Google is not stupid. People seem to think it is, however, you will find that Google understands your content just fine. The indexing mechanism is not linear, but rather semantic based and therefore very complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding Yoast.   It is partly due to their terminology.   Instead of "focus keyword" think of it as "focus phrase".   You are targeting three different keywords that you think may be searched separately, but you are putting them into Yoast together.    Instead put them each in individually.   Yoast treats the words put in together as a phrase that users search for verbatim.

You have the right basic approach for Google.   You are using keywords in the title and body in grammatically correct ways.   Hopefully in ways that sound natural to your readers and hopefully without repeating the words too often.

All you need to do is use your SEO tools differently.